# Document body is null on fullscreen

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am running into some problems when the user is using fullscreen mode(fullscreen API support within the browser)

If the user is not using the fullscreen everything seems to work fine

```
 insertBody(elx) {
    let bodyx = document.body
    bodyx.insertBefore(elx, document.body.firstChild)
 },
 removeBody(element) {
   let bodyx = document.body
   bodyx.removeChild(element)
 }
```

However if the user is in fullscreen mode `bodyx` is null

If I change `bodyx` like so

```
 bodyx = !document.body ? document.fullScreenElement : document.body
```

I get an error `Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.`

If I change `removeChild` to `remove` and pass in the element object it removes the pretty well the entire DOM

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue.  Show the code where you're going fullscreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to removing element itself:

```
removeBody(element) {
   element.remove();
}
```

Comment: Aha! When you stare at something too long and the easy answer just staring you right in the face. Thanks alot